# How to add a value to an array from another contract?

Tags: solidity, arrays

I've done it plenty of times before, but for some reason it's now throwing an error: `TypeError: Expression has to be an lvalue.`

Here's the code for the call:

```
function upvotePost(address nftContract) public payable {
    NFT nftcontract = NFT(nftContract);
    require(msg.value >= upvoteFee, 'Did not pay full upvote fee');
    nftcontract.upvoteIncrement();
    uint256 shareholderLength = nftcontract.getShareholderLength();
    uint256 shareholderIndex = shareholderLength - 1;
    nftcontract.shareholders(shareholderIndex) = msg.sender;
  }
```

and here's how the array is stored in the other contract, it's literally just a state variable:

```
address[] public shareholders;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, or at least in the way that you're trying to.
`shareholders` is a public variable, which means any contract can *read* that information, not write to it.
To make a change from a different contract, you will have to write a public or external setter function that sets `shareholders` within the contract that contains it.